# Excel formula - cut and paste losses the formula in old field

Tags: excel, validation, cut-and-paste

I have a validation in a column of an Excel spreadsheet. When I cut and paste a cell from the column, it losses the validation in that original cell. How can I avoid losing the validation in the original cell?

Comment: can you provide an example of the validation? Is it a list? Date, Time, Custom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that if you **cut** a selected cell, you will always delete also the validation of this cell.

But the cell where you copy that data will then also get the validation.

I see two possiblites to keep the validation, but both are less comfortable:

1. **copy**  paste the cell and delete the content of the source cell afterwards
2. Double click the source cell, mark only the content and then use cut paste. This will only cut the value of the cell.